# Tengo un problema con las variables de sesión en el plugin ACF en Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

Hola buenas tardes tengo una duda y espero realmente me puedan ayudar.

Estoy creando un tema para **wordpress**, y estoy usando **ACF** *(Advanced custom fields)* para guardar la informacion que el usuario necesita.

Voy a intentar mostrar un ejemplo de mi problema.

Tengo 2 paginas webs:

**home.php** -> *Lugar donde guardo la informacion del usuario en variables*

**store.php** -> *Lugar donde quiero usar las variables guardadas en home.php*

No tengo mucha experiencia usando PHP por ese motivo decidi usar **$_SESSION** vars. Intento mostrar mi informacion en todos mis archivos php; pero por algun motivo la informacion que guardo en **home.php** y luego intento usar en **store.php** no siempre se muestra.

*Para solucionar esto necesito abrir home.php y luego recargar la pagina de store.php*

Me gustaria que no fuera necesario recargar home.php para mostrar mi data en store.php

Pudieran ayudarme? No tengo idea de donde esta el problema.

Si tienen una mejor solucion para crear variables globales me gustaria escucharlos.

Estoy guardando la informacion en home.php de la siguiente manera:

**home.php**

```
session_start();
ob_start();    
$image = $_SESSION['home_image'] = get_field('home_image');
```

**store.php**

```
session_start();
ob_start();    
$image = $_SESSION['home_image'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando ACF no necesitas ese código.

Para obtener la imagen en home.php

```
$image = get_field( 'home_image' );
```

Para obtener esa imagen en cualquier otro lado necesitas el ID de la pagina donde subiste esa imagen a través de ACF y el código quedaría así para store.php

```
image = get_field( 'home_image', ID );
```

Por ejemplo, si la pagina tiene el ID 2, el código va así...

```
image = get_field( 'home_image', 2 );
```